# Java reflection call default method from derived class

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, metaprogramming, proxies

from previous posts I figured out that the way to dynamically call a default method is the following:

```
final Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();

final Constructor<Lookup> constructor =  
MethodHandles.Lookup.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class, int.class);

constructor.setAccessible(true);

final MethodHandles.Lookup defaultMethodLookup =
                constructor.newInstance(declaringClass, MethodHandles.Lookup.PRIVATE);

return defaultMethodLookup
            .unreflectSpecial(method, declaringClass)
            .bindTo(proxy)
            .invokeWithArguments(args);
```

This works perfectly fine; however, if the call is from a derived interface which overrides the specific method, then the code above invokes the method of the base interface.

So, the problem is in the case that there is a default method on a base interface, let say ‘void fire()’, and a sub interface overrides this method, then the mechanism that invokes the default methods, invokes always only the one on the base class.

Comment: Where does the *method* in the first line come from?

Comment: @waltersu its an argument to the `invoke` method of an invocation handler. The code above is inside an invocation handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the update, I managed to solve it differently.
So, basically I keep track of the current object through its proxy, therefore I got the correct (derived) method through reflection and perform the MethodLookup on that, this worked fine.
Thanks!